# Индекс установленного флажка checklistbox с#

Tags: c#, winforms

Как вернуть индекс установленного флажка checklistbox с#?

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] indexes = myCheckedListBox.CheckedIndices.Cast<int>().ToArray()
```

---

[**Источник**.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621778/checkedlistbox-and-list-of-checked-items-with-their-indexes)

Comment: Ошибка: не содержит определения для Cast